# Jboss and tomcat access log parameter setup

Tags: tomcat, jboss, localhost, server.xml, access-log

In our `$JBOSS_HOME/server/<PROFILE = default >/deploy/jbossweb.sar/server.xml` : THIS is how we have defined the logging pattern for HOW the access log file is written.

```
 <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" resolveHosts="false" directory="${jboss.server.log.dir}" pattern="combined" suffix=".log" prefix="localhost_access_log."/>
```

The alias "combined" gives you the following attributes. The order and number of attributes in this attribute set is exactly how the localhost_access_log file is written:

```
combined - %h %l %u %t "%r" %s %b "%{Referer}i" "%{User-Agent}i"
```

I checked out what each variable in that alias pattern means:

http://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/latest/api/org/apache/catalina/valves/AccessLogValve.html

Based on that template, this is what we should get:

```
128.117.140.183 - bob [04/Nov/2008:14:40:46 -0700] "GET /manager/html HTTP/1.1" 200 13022 "http://localhost:8080/"

"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.3) Gecko/2008092417 Firefox/3.0.3" 325

where %u = bob
```

Instead, THIS is what we end up getting

```
128.117.140.183 - - [04/Nov/2008:14:40:46 -0700] "GET /manager/html HTTP/1.1" 200 13022 "http://localhost:8080/"

"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.3) Gecko/2008092417 Firefox/3.0.3" 325
```

Any ideas so as to what might be causing this ?

Note that I am looking at the RIGHT access logs that are created from the RIGHT Jboss PROFILE (  / default in this case).

Why would jboss not provide the username (%u) ? Is it getting overriden somehow ?

Answer (score 1):

The %u will only show up if the user has been authenticated. How are you authenticating users ?

Comment: We are using Spring security to accomplish that.

Comment: In the web.xml we have the following block                                                                            <taglib> <taglib-uri>http://www.springframework.org/security-jboss/tags</taglib-uri>    <taglib-location> /META-INF/security-jboss.tld </taglib-location>